# Entity Framework Table-Per-Hierarchy approach for a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework Code-First for a small pet-project: a simple, browser based game. I'm trying to come up with a sensible database structure for my "items system" that also maps well to my inheritance model, but I'm running into some problems with EF here. Let me clarify the situation first:

Items themselves are unique entities within my model. There are different item types (such as "Weapon", "Armor") and for this I use Table-Per-Hierarchy inheritance. A basic example of my items classes looks like this:

```
public enum ItemType
{
    Unspecified,
    Weapon,
    Armor
}

[Table("Items")]
public abstract class Item
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public ItemType Type { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Weapon : Item
{
    [Column]
    public int MinDamage { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public int MaxDamage { get; set; }
}
```

In my model creation code I've added the following to make sure that EF uses my custom discriminator (ItemType):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
    .Map<Weapon>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue((int)ItemType.Weapon))
    .Map<Armor>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue((int)ItemType.Armor));
```

All this works fine so far; the challenge I'm facing now is to connect the items to Characters. From a database schema standpoint it seems clear to me that I should simply have a `CharactersAndItems` table. That would allow me to not only represent item ownership by characters in the game, but I can also add character-specific data for a given item; such as item durability. Representing this in code however, has proven to be a tad more tricky.

If I add a `CharacterAndItem` class I would ideally have this class hold a reference to the `Item` instance it is connected to, but then I run into the problem of not being able to get the correct derived class for that item reference (and I imagine that `Item` being an abstract class doesn't exactly help here either).

So I guess my question boils down to: how can I properly represent item ownership and meta-data such as durability for items using Entity Framework Code First?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see exactly the problem. `CharacterAndItem` can have an `Item` navigation property, even if `Item` is abstract. If you load a `CharacterAndItem` entity including the referenced `Item` for example, EF would materialize the correct concrete type, for instance `Weapon` as runtime type. Just standard OO polymorphism.

Comment: Wow, that simple... thanks a million!